# can I sniff traffic with NIC connected to network and without having IP address

Tags: networking, network-adapter, sniffing

Is it possible to sniff network traffic by just connecting to network but without assigning IP address to NIC? 
If sniffing is not possible, how easy is to guess get valid IP address if DHCP is disabled and start sniffing the traffic?

Comment: Please add the Operating System you are planning to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to sniff network traffic by just connecting to network but without assigning IP address.

Guessing a valid IP address if DHCP is disabled and you don't listen for IP addresses on the network depends on whether the address range is one of those commonly used or not.